# Must print a numerical sequence 15, 12, 24, 21, 42, 39, 78, 75, 150, 147

Tags: c

As I see it the numerical sequence consists of 2 separate sequences. This is the code that I have so far. I am not sure if you must use a while or a for loop. I am fairly new at coding so if someone please could help me.
if the entered value is 10 it must give the first 10 terms of the sequence, and if I enter 5 it must give me the first 5 terms of the sequence.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {

    int a, n = 1, t, y = 1;     // First Numerical Sequence
    int b, m = 2, s, x = 2;     // Second Numerical Sequence
    int d, r, z;            // Extra

    printf("Enter A Tn : ");
    scanf(" %d", &z);
    printf("\n");

    while (n <= z) {

        a = 15;
        r = pow(2, n - y);
        d = (9 * (r - 1)) / (2 - 1);
        t = a + d;

        printf("%d\n", t);

        n += 2;
        y++;
    }
    while (m <= z) {

        b = 12;
        r = pow(2, m - x);
        d = (9 * (r - 1)) / (2 - 1);
        s = b + d;

        printf("%d\n", s);

        m += 2;
        x++;
    }
    printf("\n");


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: stackoverflow may not be a place to answer homework imho

Comment: No, it's one sequence - formed by two alternating operations.

Comment: Format your code properly. It's very hard to work with poorly formatted code even more for beginners.

Comment: First job would be for you to identify the two operations that make up the sequence. Hint: its first grade math, no power, no complex operations.

Comment: @carlo I'm just curious... what do you think the sequence is?

Answer (score 2):

This will get the job done.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int val,ic; //iteration count, will print ic*2 number
    scanf("%d %d",&val,&ic);
    for(int i = 0;i<ic;i++){
        printf("%d ",val);
        val-=3;
        printf("%d ",val);
        val*=2;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

How to compile & run:

```
C:\Users\stike\Desktop>rem assume you saved it in a.c 
C:\Users\stike\Desktop>gcc -o a a.c
C:\Users\stike\Desktop>a
15
5
15 12 24 21 42 39 78 75 150 147
```

Comment: The code seems to do the job but... the answer would be better if you started by explaining what the sequence is.. OP obviously misunderstood that. And BTW: 1) Always check the `scanf` return value. 2) For gcc you should increase the warning level. At least add `-Wall` and also consider using `-Wextra`

Comment: It is working but not as I have hoped for. If gave "val" a value of 15, but if I give a value of 4 to "ic" it gives me 8 terms, but i only want the 4 that I asked for.

Comment: if that's the case, give `ic` 2 instead. It will print ic*2 numbers. If you want to print `x` number, give `ic` `x/2` instead.

Comment: it works for even number of terms x/2 but if i want a uneven number of terms it doesnt work.

Comment: just change `for(int i = 0;i<ic;i++)` to `for(int i = 0;i<ic+1;i++)` and recompile it.

Comment: @carlo Please consider editing your question to add *all* the informations needed to provide a suitable answer. We can see the code you wrote and what it does, but not what you were supposed to do.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print the same sequence starting from 15 and o till a certain number which the user inputs, you can follow the following code.

Hope you understood the sequence pattern when a number is given it is printed and reduce the number by 3, then it is printed and then twice the number and printed, and again reduce by 3, likewise, it flows on.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int endNum;
    int beginNum = 15;
    printf("Enter the end: ");//(lineA) here we initialize the variables with beginNum as 15
    scanf("%d", &endNum);            //(Line B) let the user to input endNum of the sequence,in the example it is 147
    while ((beginNum-3) <= endNum) {  // checks the condition
        printf("%d ", beginNum);
        
        if(beginNum==endNum) return 0; //check whether you print the end number.
        
        beginNum -= 3;  // reduce by 3
        printf("%d ", beginNum);
        beginNum *= 2;  // multiply by 2
    }

    return 0;
}
```

if you don't need to user input a endNum just initialize the value 147 to variable endNum.
And delete the lines A and B.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach using `static` variables

```
#include <stdio.h>

int next(void) {
    static int last, n = 0;
    if (n++ == 0) return last = 15;      // 1st element of sequence
    if (n % 2) return last = last * 2;   // odd elements
    return last = last - 3;              // even elements
}

int main(void) {
    for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
        printf("%d ", next());
    }
    puts("");
    return 0;
}
```